# CSS z-index seems unresponsive

Tags: html, css, positioning, z-index

I am working on a page where I am trying to create the illusion of a colored band wrapping around and behind a canvas.

To do this I have exported my graphics as two images - one which is to be located behind the canvas and one which is to be located in front.

For the canvas (.footer-container in the link below) I set position:relative and a z-index of 2, for the "behind" layer I set position:absolute and a z-index of 1 and for the "in-front" layer i did the same thing but with a z-index of 3.

But no matter what I do, I cannot seem to get any of my pictures to go behind the canvas. Currently the two IMG's are nested in the div of the canvas, but I also tried same procedure where they where not. Also, I did a similar thing another place on the same page and it works - I really can't seem to sort out what I am doing wrong?

Here is a link to the implementation:

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/706446/SFB%20html%20mockups/z-index-problem.html

Thanks!

Comment: I think the problem is, that the wrapping div#footer-container has a z-index of 2. Put the Images outside the div and it should work

Comment: Err can't test at the moment, but try: remove positioning from `footer-container` altogether, set `footer-stripes_back` `z-index` to `-1`. That *should* work... or alternatively just rearrange your elements (i.e. place the first image outside the div)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution:

Don't set a z-index on the `div#footer-container`.
Set the z-index of `div.footer-stripes_back` to -1.
You can delete the z-index of `div.footer-stripes_front`, it's not neccessary and you can leave the DOM structure as it is.
Works for me in Chrome.

Comment: Yeah! It works! Thanks for your swift replies. I had been playing around with negative values as well, but I never tried removing the z-index from #footer-container ...can anyone explain why the image with z-index:-1 jumps in front of the container with z-index:2??

Comment: That's because the outer Container defines the minimum value. So, if your outer container would have z-index 4, your inner elements only respond to z-index values >= 4.

Comment: That may be so, but when it's so easy to fix, I think it's silly not to cater to this audience as well. IE7, despite it's shoddiness, is still one of the most common browsers on the market.

Comment: We could discuss this, but this Browser is almost 6 years old and according to this (http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/39/Acid3-Internet-Explorer-7.0.png) it's not useable in a modern web.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to see the result, because the containers don't have a background.

```
#footer-top {
  background:#fff;
  position:relative;
  z-index:3; }

#footer-back {
  background:#fff;
  position:relative;
  z-index:3; }

.footer-stripes_front {      
  position:absolute;      
  z-index:4; }

.footer-stripes_back {      
  position:absolute;      
  z-index:2; }
```